# Kusto - Group by duration value to show numbers

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I use the below query to calculate the time diff between 2 events. But I am not sure how to group the duraions. I tried case function but it does not seem to work. Is there a way to group the duration . For example a pie or column chart to show number of items with durations more than 2 hours, more than 5 hours and more than 10 hours. Thanks

````
| where EventName in ('Handligrequest','Requestcomplete')
| summarize Time_diff = anyif(Timestamp,EventName == "SlackMessagePosted") - anyif(Timestamp,EventName == "ReceivedSlackMessage") by CorrelationId
| where isnotnull(Time_diff)
| extend Duration = format_timespan(Time_diff, 's')
| sort by Duration desc```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Generate data sample. Not part of the solution
let t = materialize (range i from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend Time_diff  = 24h*rand());
// Solution Starts here
t
| summarize count() by time_diff_range = case(Time_diff >= 10h, "10h <= x", Time_diff >= 5h, "5h <= x < 10h", Time_diff >= 2h, "2h <= x < 5h", "x < 2h")
| render piechart
```

| time_diff_range | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 10h <= x | 590 |
| 5h <= x < 10h | 209 |
| x < 2h | 89 |
| 2h <= x < 5h | 112 |

[image: Pie Chart]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12Py2rDMBBF9wb/w8Uru4TYMfUqcbbddZPug2qPK4ElGWkMScjHd0T6oN0IiXtmzlVd44UcBcWEUbFCVHaZaYtXz1hUYPgJrAnRzysb7/JsJgajh5WZYNRsboQyKPdBMJiCt9iBPXZN0yAyLfK8gy5MbsSbsXQezTRBFrTP%20knmxrKq9nlW1zh9OXBiMUdoCpRnnGd3xNVaFZJq8KvjssL7Ffy97fzQ9xhUpPJXcuylht6gkBOHHpdigz9pl8LukeGQ4P9Em4j2h%20gSUKRbq4sqNQvyLwpYDA1aWn8CgvLjclEBAAA=)

Comment: Thanks it works for me. I was able to summarize again and render the chart.